# How do i select result set without caching in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to run NOn_cached queries using rails. Any help?

Comment: You don't want the database to cache it or the application?

Comment: Yes sir, i want database to avoid the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is only going to cache the query result DURING the request-response cycle, so it's only going to live for the duration of the request.

You should be able to use the uncached command

uncached do
  find(blah)
end

at least within a controller action.

Another (BAD!) way to do it is add a query attribute that busts the cache

where("name= ? OR 0= ?", 'smith', rand(100))

or similar, so that you get OR '0=0.3567' which is always false AND different for each request.

You *really* want to use uncached though :)